# Native Base Tab Component does not Work On Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

I'm trying to add Native Base Tab component to my project with using Expo. I completely went through Native Base's own example to test whether it does work or not, but could not make it work any tab.

Also, to check if any dependency cause problem **I test it on new Expo project and tabs again did not work.** 
Therefore **I test tabs without using Expo and it worked**. So, I am sure the problem is Expo but I do not know how to solve it. I'll write my dependency below thank you for any help.

The part that tab does not work is that there is no change when I click Tab2 or Tab3 it is stuck on Tab1(initial Tab). Also, it does not the content of any Tab including initial Tab (Tab1).

My Dependency:

```
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"expo": "^32.0.0",
"native-base": "^2.12.0",
"react": "16.5.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-pie-chart": "^1.0.13",
"react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
"react-native-swiper-flatlist": "^1.0.9",
"react-native-ui-kitten": "^3.1.2",
"react-navigation": "^3.3.2"
```

The example code of Native Base Tab:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Content, Tab, Tabs } from 'native-base';
import Tab1 from './tabOne';
import Tab2 from './tabTwo';
import Tab3 from './tabThree';
export default class TabsExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header hasTabs />
        <Tabs>
          <Tab heading="Tab1">
            <Tab1 />
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading="Tab2">
            <Tab2 />
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading="Tab3">
            <Tab3 />
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

native bases tab component is a little buggy

try to use this library

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view

but i would say try to make your tabs with navigation libraries which you are using
like react-native-navigation or router-flux

Comment: yeah that's awesome